# Need a small compression rod for stabilizing my dryer

Tags: dryer

Just joined and looking for some help in finding (or building) a small compression rod to stabilize my dryer. I have washer/dryer closet and the dryer sits atop my washer (in classic fashion). However, when the washer goes into a fast spin, the dryer shakes on top a bit and makes some noise. I realized if I could just get some small (say around 3" or 4") compression rods on either side of the dryer (between it and the closet wall), it would really help to stabilize the movement and the sound.

The closest I could find through web searching is 6"curtain rods, which are just too long and too weak. Ideally, I'm looking for something like what I'm showing in the illustration below. Big suction cup like ends would be great but as long as it's a fairly wide, flat surface, it could be anything (plastic, rubber, etc.). Any ideas where I could find something like this or how I could build it?

[image: compression rod illustration]

Comment: You can find urethane bumpers that size, but I'm not sure if it'd hold the washing machine too rigidly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you get yourself some high density foam material similar to the type used for padding furniture cushions. You can get this material in various thicknesses so you would want to measure the gap from the sides of the dryer and the walls and purchase accordingly. [One Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H2QS5RE)

The idea is to cut the high density padding into a square of say 1.5 or 2.0 feet on a side. Then squeeze that in between the wall and the dryer sides. You will want the material to be under some compression when it is installed. It may be necessary to insert two pads of different thicknesses on top of each other to get the needed space filled up with some compression.

This approach has some decided advantages as follows:

1. The foam material will act to muffle the sound coupled to the wall. Your idea with point contact will more likely couple sound right into the wall.
2. The foam pad extends out over a larger area of the dryer sides to provide stability and to reduce the drum head effect that metal appliance walls can create.
3. The pad spreads the compression load over a large surface of the wall to prevent wall damage. A point type of compression assembly would have to be positioned over a stud to ensure that it does not eventually break into the wall. This would be particularly an issue for the very common drywall material made of paper and plaster material. With the foam that load gets spread across a large area.

Answer (score 0):

You may accomplish maximum flexibility in your design objective by using, as you suggest, suction cups combined with either bolts or threaded rod. The key factor, however, is to use a coupling nut, also called a joining nut:

[image: Coupling nut]

Unfortunately, I've not yet found reverse threaded coupling nuts similar to a turnbuckle in which one rotates the nut causing the items to separate. It would be necessary in this method to hold the nut and one suction cup while rotating the other to the necessary spacing.

Alternatively, if you are able to find a correctly sized turnbuckle, you may be able to modify it to serve your purposes. I was about to suggest that you replace the threaded hooks or eyes in the turnbuckle with the suction cup bolts, but one of those hooks or eyes is left-hand threaded!
[image: home depot turnbuckle]